# Pokemon GO sign up ERROR

Tags: pokemon-go

When I was making an account for pokemon GO with my kid, it said to make a trainer club account. So I did. But then when I put in my kids date of birth, it said to send an email to my email address. So then I got it. It told me to create my own account, so I tried to, but it wouldn't let me to it. Instead my child's birth date would come up, with the only button on the screen being : continue. I don't know what to do and my child really wants to play this game!

Comment: It sounds like your kid is too young to have an account of their own, and the age you put in isn't allowed by the system. I would try contacting support to fix this or just using a different email account.

Comment: @Broneironaut it is possible for parents to allow their kids to create trainer accounts even if they're too young. In that case the parents will be emailed a guide how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create a Child account, so it should work properly.

1. Use a different browser if you run into trouble. My Firefox didn't work, but using IE did the trick.
2. Create your own account - or log in, if you already have one. It works either way.
   The log in / sign up page can be found [here](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/login).

   2.1 If you create a new account, follow the steps and don't forget to verify it.
3. Once you're logged in you can add your kid's account by clicking on the button "*Add a Child*" [image]
4. Follow the steps...

   4.1 Enter Date of Birth and real name of your kid. (If your kid is 13 or older you can no longer create a child's account. With that age they need to do it alone.)

   4.2 Enter Username, Screen Name, Password and the kid's mail address (You can as well use your own mail address). Your kid can not change these info afterwards - only you can. Do NOT use your kid's real name as Screen Name.
5. Done. The Child Account should now appear in your menu (see screenshot above). Your kid can now use the newly created account.